# Vertically aligned multi-line elements within div with scroll on overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align a set of elements (each of which may be multi-line) to the middle of a div AND also have the overflow be scrolled. I'm able to vertically align the multi-line content via display:table and display:table-cell, but this seems to disable any overflow handling. Separately, I've tried using the line-height trick (setting line-height to the height of the containing div), but the vertical alignment doesn't seem to work with multiple lines of content.

Does a pure CSS solution exist?

Here's a fiddle that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/arxoq7oq/1/ (updated)

Here's my html:

```
<body>
    <p>Goal: Vertically align to middle with scroll upon overflow - Scenarios A and B need to be handled with the same code (unlike currently):</p>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario A
      <div class="container green">
        <div class="item-list1">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario B
      <div class="container green">
        <div class="item-list2">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
          <div class="item">Item 3</div>
          <div class="item">Item 4</div>
          <div class="item">Item 5</div>
          <div class="item">Item 6</div>
          <div class="item">Item 7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Can achieve vertical alignment to middle, but overflow scroll doesn't work:</p>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario A
      <div class="container green">
        <div class="item-list1">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario B
      <div class="container red">
        <div class="item-list1">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
          <div class="item">Item 3</div>
          <div class="item">Item 4</div>
          <div class="item">Item 5</div>
          <div class="item">Item 6</div>
          <div class="item">Item 7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Can achieve overflow scroll, but vertical alignment to middle doesn't work:</p>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario A
      <div class="container red">
        <div class="item-list2">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame">
      Scenario B
      <div class="container green">
        <div class="item-list2">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2 might wrap to multiple lines</div>
          <div class="item">Item 3</div>
          <div class="item">Item 4</div>
          <div class="item">Item 5</div>
          <div class="item">Item 6</div>
          <div class="item">Item 7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:100%;
}

.green {background:chartreuse;}

.red {background:crimson;}

.frame {display:inline-block;}

.container {
    display:table;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
}

.item-list1 {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow-y:auto; /* Does nothing with table-cell*/  
}

.item-list2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    vertical-align:middle; /* Does nothing without table-cell */    
}

.item {
    margin:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly do not completely understand why and how this technique works, but it does!!!!!! It is based on the aligning technique described at the end of [this article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

For the result check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arxoq7oq/5/). Note how the first example with Scenario A and B have the same class applied to it!!!

Here is the css that did the job:

```
.container {
    display:block;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.item-list1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 8em;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another trick to vertical align a block is :

```
.block-parent { 
    position: relative; 
}

.block-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this trick. However, the height of the child block must be specified in order for overflow handling to work and the content is variable in size. So, this doesn't solve the problem with just CSS, but it might be the best approach to solving it with javascript.